# javafx tableView getting previous Item

Tags: javafx, tableview

Hey im doing a Playlist for Music and im doing the previous and Forward button but i dont know how i get the file before/ after the current one. I use this for the current

```
play(tableView.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem());
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For previous, use

```
int currentIndex = tableView.getSelectionModel().getSelectedIndex();
tableView.getItems().get(currentIndex - 1);
```

and similarly for next. You will want to add checks for the range (i.e. don't get the previous item if `currentIndex == 0`, and similarly for next).